# Regex like syntax in SQL query python

Tags: python, sql, regex, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have some code which I have to write again in order to be production ready. The code is messy and I have a few lines that indicate sql queries, but I can not resolve the exact statements.

```
qs = 'DEVICENAME1|DEVICENAME2|DEVICENAME3'

qstring='SELECT "lat", "lon", "device", "location" FROM "locations" WHERE ("device" =~ /^('+qs+')/) AND time > now()-60h'

qstring='SELECT "device", "lat" FROM "locations" WHERE ("location"=~ /^'+loc+'$/) AND time > now()-60h'
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could resolve the sql query statements for me. To be clear I am interested in these parts:
`("device" =~ /^('+qs+')/)`
`("location"=~ /^'+loc+'$/)`

Comment: Which database are you using? Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: influxdb python. I added the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, `"device" =~ /^('+qs+')/` means: check if the device that starts with `qs` (`^` represents the beginning of the string), and `"location"=~ /^'+loc+'$/`  checks that the location is equal to `loc` (`$` is the end of string).

So, in almost any database, these conditions could be rewritten without the use of regexes:

```
"device" like ' + qs+ '%  -- influxdb does not support like
"location" = ' + loc + '
```

Side note: you should be using prepared statements and parameterized queries everywhere, for you security and efficiency. Since you are rewriting legacy code, this is a good spot to do so now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I am trying to rewrite the whole code. Can you explain why the + characters required before and after the variables, please?

Comment: The `+` is the string concatenation operator in python (not sql). Hence my point about prepared statements (I don’t know much about influxdb but it should support prepared statements...)

Answer (score 0):

A complete explanation can be found at the documentation:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/data_exploration/#syntax-15
Influxdb supports Golang's regular expression syntax.